# How do I make a JQuery Slider-like feature on iPhone/Android web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, slider

In the iPhone or Android, if you have a JQuery Slider, it doesn't quite work (touchscreen will move the screen instead of drag the slider.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to write this from scratch. Luckily, @[ppk](http://twitter.com/ppk) has coded up an example of [drag and drop for iPhone](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/tests/drag.html).

Answer (score 2):

Listen for [touch events](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/) and move the slider accordingly. These events also work on Android as it also uses WebKit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library http://touchpunch.furf.com/ 
This provides touch events for all the jquery ui elements.

Answer (score 1):

I found sample code online which converts touch events to mouse events. I tested this with jquery-ui's slider and it worked nicely!

[Link to source](http://rossboucher.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for iphone, android and windows phones via jquery+javascript. Windows phone with IE has one flaw, I have not been able to get it to snap to div sections.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to wire up http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/ the slider.  Works like a charm, just be sure to replace the code that works against specific dom elements.    Then add $('#sliderdiv').addTouch (). Works on IPhone, but doesn't work for Android.  According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html) touch events don't work on Android.

Comment: Better yet, use JQuery Mobile.