# Cannot get the jQuery Vertical Slider to work on the iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, slider

I am trying to get [jQuery Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical) to work on the iPad but failing at every attempt I do!
Please does anyone know how to do this? Many Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 6):

Adding the "Touch Punch" plugin will add touch-support to current jQuery UI plugins: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery mobile rather than jquery UI - jQuery mobile is specifically designed with touch based devices in mind.

You can see the slider functionality here: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at touchstart, touchend and touchmove events for idevices. Take a look at

[How do I make a JQuery Slider-like feature on iPhone/Android web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422022/how-do-i-make-a-jquery-slider-like-feature-on-iphone-android-web-app)